# How Do I change the value of a cell based on another cell in scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following function on cell X2

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Sleep",B2))=true,"No","Yes")
```

I'd like to create a script that will do this that I will trigger upon form submit.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need an installable trigger function. Upon form submit, your function will receive an event argument that includes the spreadsheet range where the form values have been inserted, and a copy of the values themselves (so you don't need to read the sheet). See "Spreadsheet Form Submit Events" in [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).

```
function updateX2onFormSubmit( event ) {
  var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  // Get a range object, at column X in event row.
  cellX = sheet.getRange( "X" + event.range.getRow() );

  cellX.setValue( event.values[1] == "Sleep" ? "Yes" : "No" );
}
```